# What's the point of @RequestParam if I don't use it and it still works?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

```
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public String h(String title){
    System.out.println(title);
    return "view";
}
```

.

```
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public String h(@RequestParam String title){
    System.out.println(title);
    return "view";
}
```

When accessing /api?title=something, both of them work as expected. So what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works only if the requestParam sent matches with your variable name.

Try changing it like this

```
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public String h(@RequestParam String myTitle){
    System.out.println(myTitle);
    return "view";
}
```

and see what happens. `myTitle` will be null.

On the other hand, If you use `@RequestParam` it can still work with different variable name.
Try this.

```
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public String h(@RequestParam("title") String myTitle){
    System.out.println(myTitle);
    return "view";
}
```

Another thing is you can set `@RequestParam(required = false)`, if you want some params as optional.

Answer (score 0):

You can try code like that:

`@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
    public String h(@RequestParam(value = "title", required = false) String title) {
         System.out.println(title);
         return "view";
    }`